# limit of the following telescoping sequence

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

The answer i got is $0.25 $.beacuse evey term gets cancelled like telescoping sequence. am i correct?

Comment: $$\dfrac4{a_ma_{m-1}}=\dfrac{a_m-a_{m-1}}{a_ma_{m-1}}=?$$

Comment: what does this mean? i am sorry i didn't understand

Answer (score 2):

lab bhattacharjee gave you a great hint. More concretely,
$$
\frac{1}{a_i a_{i+1}}=\frac{1}{4}\frac{a_{i+1}-a_{i}}{a_i a_{i+1}} = \frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{a_i}-\frac{1}{a_{i+1}} \right).
$$
Can you proceed from this?

Comment: yes i have done it this way and that means that the limit is $0.25$.thanku